# Class label 1 not present

Tags: python, data-science

I'm using Decision Tree Classifier with class weights {0:0.2, 1:0.8}, but I got an error "Class label 1 not present.", can anyone help me to fix this problem? thank you.

There is the link to my code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1riuGXWXKnfH8GbqlpFV1RC41gn2mMtIn?usp=sharing

```
# Drop dependent variable from dataframe and create the X(independent variable) matrix
x = data.drop(columns = 'BAD')
# Create dummy variables for the categorical variables - Hint: use the get_dummies() function
x = pd.get_dummies(x, drop_first = True)
# Create y(dependent varibale)
y = data['BAD']

# Split the data into training and test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1) 

#Defining Decision tree model with class weights class_weight={0: 0.2, 1: 0.8}
d_tree =  DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight = {0:0.2, 1:0.8})

#fitting Decision tree model
d_tree.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCDpo.png)

Comment: Did you understand *where* class label 1 is missing?

Comment: Stack Overflow prefers you AVOID screenshots of code and external links to your code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question Please cut & paste the relevant code here.  We cannot tell the order in which you're executing cells in an external notebook.  Please help us help you by putting all your code in the question.

Comment: In addition, please expand the "3 frames" of the traceback and paste all of that; it generally contains very useful debugging information.

Comment: What do you get if you run `y.unique()`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.